# SQLSERVER - LOCK error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm getting an error while running a proc. through SSIS..
Error:

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "Exec clk.id_Process ?
>   ,? ,?" failed with the following error: "The instance of the SQL
>   Server Database Engine cannot obtain a LOCK resource at this time.
>   Rerun your statement when there are fewer active users. Ask the
>   database administrator to check the lock and memory configuration for
>   this instance, or to check for long-running transactions.". Possible
>   failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set
>   correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established
>   correctly.

I tried to trace out the problem by joining

```
"sys.dm_exec_sessions AS s
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests AS r ON r.session_id = s.session_id
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) AS st"
```

and found its getting strucked while updating a table

```
UPDATE ta        
        SET ta.id =
        CASE 
            WHEN ta.id=tmp.MergeoldId THEN tmp.MergenewId
            ELSE ta.id
        END,
        ta.Id2=
        CASE
         WHEN ta.Id2=tmp.MergeoldId THEN tmp.MergenewId
         ELSE ta.Id2
        END,
        ta.Id3=
        CASE
            WHEN ta.Id3=tmp.MergeoldId THEN tmp.MergenewId
            ELSE ta.Id3
        END
        --SELECT ta.id ,ta.Id2,ta.Id3, tmp.MergeoldId,*
        FROM tel.TranAssemble ta WITH (ROWLOCK)
        INNER JOIN clk.id_Process tmp WITH (NOLOCK) on (ta.id = tmp.MergeoldId OR ta.Id2=tmp.MergeoldId OR ta.Id3=tmp.MergeoldId )
        WHERE tmp.Id >= @MinId AND tmp.Id < @MINID +  @BatchSize
```

Any solution?

Comment: please post the output of DMV to in the question..

Answer (score 2):

These issues are due to Memory pressure ,since [The lock manager will not use more than 60 percent of the memory available to SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337440.aspx).

> SQL Server cannot obtain a lock resource. This can be caused by either of the following reasons:
> SQL Server cannot allocate more memory from the operating system, either because other processes are using it, or because the server is operating with the max server memory option configured.
> The lock manager will not use more than 60 percent of the memory available to SQL Server.

Normally SQL server uses locks for all queries (even selects) and a small amount of memory is used for each lock it holds(96 bytes).

Based on the above knowledge,you can start troubleshooting your issue using below queries

```
--this gives you currently running queries holding more locks
select * from sys.dm_exec_requests ec
cross apply
(SELECT request_session_id, COUNT (*) num_locks
FROM sys.dm_tran_locks trn
where ec.session_id=trn.request_session_id
GROUP BY request_session_id 
)b

--this gives you locks for allsessions
SELECT request_session_id, COUNT (*) num_locks
FROM sys.dm_tran_locks trn
where ec.session_id=trn.request_session_id
GROUP BY request_session_id
```